# PTIJ: What does this Mishnah Mean?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Avot 1:10 says:

> שְׁמַעְיָה וְאַבְטַלְיוֹן קִבְּלוּ מֵהֶם. שְׁמַעְיָה אוֹמֵר, אֱהֹב אֶת
> הַמְּלָאכָה, וּשְׂנָא אֶת הָרַבָּנוּת, וְאַל תִּתְוַדַּע לָרָשׁוּת:
>
> Shmaya and Avtalon accepted the tradition from them. Shmaya said: Love
> work, hate Rabbis, and don't say Vidui to the Government.

Why should we hate Rabbis, and why can't we say Vidui to the government?

Chazal also stated:

> תְּפִלַּת עַרְבִית רְשׁוּת
>
> The Maariv Prayer is the government

What does this statement mean in light of the above?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer for now...

I'm going to take my chance on perhaps offending some people, inadvertantly, by saying this, but, hey, it's Purim, so laugh it away:

There are numerous yeshiva rabbis that have discouraged students from working and instead they are spending their entire day in the Bet Midrash. Let's cut to the chase, shall we? After these boys get married and have to support a family, they have no income and they become a burden to the parents and, frequently, part of the community. Guess who "hates" the rabbis, as a result? The parents.

**"Don't say Viduy to the government"**

Smart advice coming from *Pirkei Avot*. There's another Mishnah in *Pirkeu Avot* (B"N, will edit in the location, later) that says that you shouldn't become friendly with them because they rely upon you only when they need you but when you need them, they won't help you.

Well, given that concept, you would expect that normally when you confess your sins, someone is listening and will forgive you. Hah! Have you tried apologizing to any government authority for a federal crime? Maybe they will reduce the sentence, but, they won't forgive you completely.

Ever been late paying your taxes to the IRS? Even if you apologize to them, you'll still have to pay penalties on the lateness, but they will never completely excuse what you owe them.

In short, it's a waste of time!

I'll try to address the other areas, later...

Comment: Ouch. <fofteen>